# ¿Por que sale comentarios en los componentes que no se visualizan en VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

¿Alguien sabe como quitar esos "comentarios" esto en VueJS?
Realmente no es un problema. Pero... en lo personal me fastidia con solo verlos :')

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y donde estas viendo eso?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres?

Comment: Donde es que ves esos comentarios.. en el render del navegador?

Comment: Si, exactamente.

Comment: Creo que deberias preguntarle a evan you ( el creador de vue) o al renderizado del navegador. Si no pusiste eso en tu codigo, alguien en algun paso lo agrego